# Does the way of database connection, opening and closing in python affect the performance of the code?

Tags: python, sql, database, performance

I am using the code below in a loop which is excecuted several times. I doubt that in the end of the code, creating and closing the database in an inappropriate way which slows down the performance of the program. Do i have to open, create cursors and close the connection everytime?

```
"""
Connecting to Database and putting data into in
"""

db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","xxxx","Data")
cursor=db.cursor()


#checking phase to stop scrapping

sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM AppartRent WHERE Short_link=%s"""

rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))
print rows

if rows>=1:
duplicate_count+=1
print duplicate_count

if duplicate_count>=100:


print "The program has started getting duplicates now- The program is terminating"
        sys.exit()
else:
    query="""INSERT INTO AppartRent (Sale_Rent, Type, Area, Title,Price, PricePerSqrFt, Bedroom,Agency_Fee, Bathroom, Size,ZonedFor, Freehold, Prop_ref,Furnished_status,Rent_payment,Building_info,Amenities,Trade_name,Licence, RERA_ID,Phone_info,Short_link) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    cursor.execute(query,(Sale_Rent_result,Type_result,area_result, title_result, price_result, Pricepersq_result, bedroom_result, agencyfee_result, bathroom_result, size_result,Zoned_for_result, Freehold_result, propertyref_result, furnished_result, rent_is_paid_result, building_result, Amenities_result, tradename_result, licencenum_result, reraid_result, phone_result, link_result))


db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a SQL question. However what I do know is this method puts way more strain on your server than other methods. I doubt it will slow your program down signifiantly, depending on the response time of your servers.

Is it not possible to grab all of the information at once and store it in in memory within the program?

I don't have experience in python but I would think this should be possible.